# File (not image) doc/pdf is not uploaded in vue and laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to upload a pdf /doc file using VUE and laravel but after submitting, The file shows no value.

I have a VUE component with this form and this script:

```js
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      product_list: false,
      add_form: true,
      edit_form: false,

      form: {
        po_order_docs: '',
      },
      errors: {},
    };
  },
  methods: {
    processFile() {
      this.file = _this.$refs.file.files[0];
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('this.form.po_order_docs', this.file);
    },
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Order Docs</label>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input m-input" id="file" @change="processFile()" ref="file" />
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="file">Choose file</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check for `enctype multipart form-data`

Comment: In from  enctype="multipart/form-data"